# add_action function in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, action, addition

well im learning to create a wordpress plugin
i downloaded one and read the codes, and i saw this
i assume 'foo' is the tag where it will add action to..

but what does the array() exactly do?

```
add_action('foo', array('foo1', 'foo2'));
```

i looked at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action
and there is no clear definition about it ..

Comment: you could check this reference - [usage of add action](http://w4dev.com/wp/add_action/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, the first argument is the tag (to which you'll be adding the action), and the second argument specifies the function to call (i.e. your callback).

The second argument takes in a PHP callback, and as such, accepts a number of valid forms. Check this out for all of them :

[PHP Callback Pseudo-Types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

The type you've shown above is of type 2. The first element of the array specifies a class, and the second element specifies which function of the class you'd like to call.

So with the example you've given above, what that will do is that, whenever the `foo()` action is called, it will eventually call `foo1->foo2()` as well.

Comment: thank you richard, i understand it (almost) xD

so you mean foo1 is the class and foo2 is the method within the class right?

hell, i need to learn oop in php xD
thanks guys sorry for such a dumb question :P

Comment: @kapitanluffy - can you please mark this question as answered

Comment: Is that right that foo2() must be static? Why is that? This effectively means you can't pass into objects only class definitions?

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of the `add_action` function is the function to be called with the hook.

```
function hello_header() {
 echo "I'm in the header!"; 
}

add_action('wp_head', 'hello_header');
```

The usage of an array as the second argument is to pass a objects method rather than just a regular function.

Have a read up on the how the `call_user_func` works. Should provide some more insight.

<s>`http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback`</s>(dead link)