# How do I use className::method()/array('className', 'method') in add_action('init', '')

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new to WP, and still have to study more concepts, good practices and functions. Besides, my english isn't pretty good. So, take it easy :P

I was trying to develop my own plugin when I got a trouble with `add_action('init', '')` (not sure yet). Here is my class (named MeuPlugin):

```
private static $wpdb;

public static function initialize(){
    global $wpdb;

    //add_action('init', MeuPlugin::newslettersPostType());
    add_action('init', array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType'));
    add_action('admin_menu', array('MeuPlugin', 'addMenu'));

    MeuPlugin::$wpdb = $wpdb;
}

public static function install(){
    if (is_null(MeuPlugin::$wpdb)) MeuPlugin::initialize();
}

public static function newslettersPostType() { 
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Newsletters'),
        'singular_name' => __('Newsletter'),
        'add_new' => __('Adicionar Novo'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Novo Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Editar Item'),
        'new_item' => __('Novo Item'),
        'view_item' => __('Ver Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Procurar Itens'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nenhum registro encontrado'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nenhum registro encontrado na lixeira'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Newsletters'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'public_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,          
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        //'register_meta_box_cb' => 'newsletters_meta_box',     
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt')
    );

    register_post_type('newsletters', $args);
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}

public static function addMenu(){
    add_options_page('MeuPlugin - Gerenciamento','MeuPlugin',10,__FILE__,array("MeuPlugin","testPage"));
}

public static function testPage(){
    echo '...';
}
```

And then I use

```
$pluginFile = substr(strrchr(dirname(__FILE__),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR),1).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename(__FILE__);

register_activation_hook($pluginFile, array('MeuPlugin', 'install'));

add_filter('init', array('MeuPlugin', 'initialize'));
```

to "run" my plugin.

My question: why `add_action('init', array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType'));` ("line" 7) doesn't work, while `add_action('admin_menu', array('MeuPlugin', 'addMenu'));` ("line" 8) does?

P.S.: when I use `add_action('init', MeuPlugin::newslettersPostType());` ("line" 6) instead of `add_action('init', array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType'));` ("line" 7), it works fine. Why I have to put `className::method()` instead of `array('className', 'method')`?

I hope I have been clear. Thanks!

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597971/add-action-function-in-wordpress will answer your question

Comment: @Laurentiu I still can't see why `add_action('init', array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType'))` doesn't work and `add_action('admin_menu', array('MeuPlugin', 'addMenu'))` does. These aren't the "same thing"?  Did I miss something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the "add_action" function defined like this:

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
    return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

1st param is a string; 
2nd param is a reference to function  and not an array as you tried to use

```
 array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType')
```

Currently i cannot explain why the line 8 :

```
add_action('admin_menu', array('MeuPlugin', 'addMenu'));
```

is working..... it shouldn't

Comment: thanks for response! I think `array('MeuPlugin', 'newslettersPostType')` also works like a callback function, but using as array. See [Callbacks / Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#example-109) In my case, using `// Type 2: Static class method call
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));`